# How to fix header in submenu of jQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I am very new to jQuery and couldn't solve the following problem: I have a main menu and a click on the main menu opens a sub menu with multiple items.

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"> </script>
</head>
```

```
<div role="main" class="ui-content" style="background-color:#dae5f4;">
  <div class="ui-field-contain">
    <!-- ui-field-contain to wrap select elements -->
    <label for="items" class="select">Sub-Header</label> 
    <select id="items" name="items" size="1" data-native-menu="false">
      <option value="">Main-Header</option>
      <option value=1>Item 1</option>
      <option value=2>Item 2</option>
      <option value=3>Item 3</option>
      <option value=4>Item 4</option>
      <option value=5>Item 5</option>
      <option value=6>Item 6</option>
      <option value=7>Item 7</option>
      <option value=8>Item 8</option>
      <option value=9>Item 9</option>
      <option value=10>Item 10</option>
      <option value=11>Item 11</option>
      <option value=12>Item 12</option>
      <option value=13>Item 13</option>
      <option value=14>Item 14</option>
      <option value=15>Item 15</option>
      <option value=16>Item 16</option>
      <option value=17>Item 17</option>
      <option value=18>Item 18</option>
      <option value=19>Item 19</option>
      <option value=20>Item 20</option>
      <option value=21>Item 21</option>
      <option value=22>Item 22</option>
      <option value=23>Item 23</option>
      <option value=24>Item 24</option>
      <option value=25>Item 25</option>
      <option value=26>Item 26</option>
      <option value=27>Item 27</option>
      <option value=28>Item 28</option>
      <option value=29>Item 29</option>
      <option value=30>Item 30</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <!-- end of div class=ui-field-contain -->
</div>
<!-- end of div role main -->
```

Now, I want to fix the Sub-Header so that it doesn't scroll with all the items any longer. Unfortunately, `data-position="fixed"` didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it using CSS.
If you want to limit the height of the popup to not scroll when it is open, you can use 60vh of max-height or similar and set vertical scroll.

```
.ui-selectmenu.ui-dialog .ui-content {
  max-height: 60vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

And in order to fix it if you want, add this CSS:

```
#items-dialog {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Azametzin! Is there a possibility, to change the color of the X in the left upper corner by CSS when an item is selected?

Comment: You can select it with CSS using the class ``.ui-btn-icon-notext``, but I recommend you using a class to wrap everything to be more specific in selection. I didn't get what you mean by "when an item is selected".